# has anyone got xmlbeans to work with GSON?

Tags: java, gson, xmlbeans

Basically as above.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
ErrorsDocument er = ErrorsDocument.Factory.newInstance();
er.setError("monkey escaped");
System.out.println(gson.toJson(er));
```

craps out with:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: How
>   can the type variable not be present
>   in the class declaration!     at
>   com.google.gson.TypeInfoFactory.getIndex(TypeInfoFactory.java:127)
>     at
>   com.google.gson.TypeInfoFactory.getActualType(TypeInfoFactory.java:93)
>     at
>   com.google.gson.TypeInfoFactory.getTypeInfoForField(TypeInfoFactory.java:54)

etc

Comment: Was this issue resolved?